# Is using shred to wipe Linux SSDs safe?

Tags: linux, ssd

I’m using shred from the CLI on a live GParted flash drive to wipe two 1TB SSD drives in my laptop that was running various installations and re-installations of Linux for quite a while.

Will shred damage them? I ask because I've been told that using shred on SSD drives is not good.

They are hybrids so I figured I’d be good. I've already started but figured I’d ask!  Once done, I’ll be installing Qubes as a daily driver.  I just wanted to wipe them before a fresh and permanent installation.

Comment: `shred` is complete overkill for this. A plain format would do, and if you are paranoid do a `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdX`.

Comment: Gotcha...  I’ll probably do the paranoid thing and dd it

Comment: SSDs use wear levelling, so `shred` can't guarantee the old data is wiped (though it *probably* will, given enough writes). However, writes for SSDs are limited, so it will use up quite a few write cycles, which is **very** bad if you want to re-use the SSDs for a new installation. Same for `dd`. TL;DR: Don't use `shred`, don't use `dd`, use Secure Erase as described in the answer below.

Comment: Relatd: https://askubuntu.com/questions/794612/how-to-securely-wipe-files-from-ssd-drive

Answer (score 12):

Before resorting to `shred`, see if the drives [support Secure Erase](https://tinyapps.org/docs/wipe_drives_hdparm.html), which will make sure that *all* possible regions on the drive are erased. Despite all the talk about SSDs supporting Secure Erase, quite a few HDDs support it and thus it is easy to believe that SSHDs would as well.

```
# hdparm -I /dev/sdX
 ...
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 65534
        supported
     ...
        supported: enhanced erase

 # hdparm --user-master u --security-set-pass p /dev/sdx
  ...
 # hdparm --user-master u --security-erase p /dev/sdX
  ...
```

Note that there are further requirements for having the drive allow the Secure Erase operation; see the above article or similar.

Comment: Additionally/Instead you can also use `hdparm --user-master u --security-erase-enhanced p /dev/sdx` for _Enhanced Secure Erase_. However, for modern drives it is unlikely to make a difference.
For more information about the difference between [ATA Secure Erase and ATA Enhanced Secure Erase have a look on Security Stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/62253/what-is-the-difference-between-ata-secure-erase-and-security-erase-how-can-i-en#64480). For modern drives it should not matter what you use, it is as safe – or unsafe – as the other one.